# Prove that the given set is a finite set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

$A = \{(a,b) \in N^2 | (2+a)(2-b) \ge 2(a-b)\}$. Prove that A is a finite set.

I'm having problem with proving A is a finite set. So far,

Let $x, y \in A$. Then,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    (2+x)(2-y) &\ge 2(x-y)\\
    4-2y+2x-xy &\ge 2x-2y\\
    4-xy &\ge 0\\
    xy &\le 4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

This is what I have, but I'm not sure that showing $xy \le 4$ is enough to show that we have finite set. The reason why I thought this was enough because x and y are natural numbers. I searched other proofs and saw someone used contradiction to prove this is a finite set by assuming A is a infinite set. Do you guys think I need contradiction? or is it enough to prove A is a finite set?

Comment: In the definition for the set $A$ you have $(2 + a)(2 -b) \leq 2(a-b)$ but then you changed it to $(2+x)(2-y) \geq 2(x-y)$. Which of them is correct? The first one would lead to $4 \leq xy$ - which would not yield a finite set, so i think the latter is correct.

In that case you could argue that for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $y \leq \frac{4}{x}$ gives you $y \leq 4$. Analogously you get $x \leq 4$ and therefore you have a finite set of combinations. (Note that not all of them are possible, e.g. $(x,y) = (3,3)$, but a subset of a finite set is still finite.)

Comment: @Octavius Oh, sorry my mistake. It supposed to be $A = \{(a,b) \in N^2 | (2+a)(2-b) \ge 2(a-b)\}$. I just edited. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Does your definition of $\mathbb N$ exclude $0$? If not, then $A$ is infinite since it contains the pair $(0,n)$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: @posilon $\mathbb{N}$ does exclude $0$. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's fine to show directly it's a finite set if that is what you're trying to prove! Your proof is fine. If we write it out very explicitly: you have shown shown for an *arbitrary* element $(x,y) \in A$, we have $xy \leq 4$. Since we know that $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, this then implies that ($x=1 \text{ and } y=4$) or ($x=2 \text{ and } y=2$) or ($x=4 \text{ and } y=1)$ etc. There will only be a finite number of terms here (you can write them all out explicility). Hence you've shown whenever $(x,y)$ is any element of $A$, it must be either $(1,4)$ or $(2,2)$ or $(4,1)$ or one of these other finitely many solutions.

I.e. you have proven that $A\subset \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1)\}$ (in fact we have exact equality by the contrapositive statement that not being one of these pairs means you are not in $A$). So obviously $A$ is a finite set!

Also, I can't see a way to prove this by contradiction that is more straightforward than what you've done. What you've done proves that the number of solutions for the equation, and hence the elements of $A$, is a finite number. You could say that if $A$ were infinite, then $A$ would have to contain a solution that is not one of the possible ones. But this is entirely pointless, as the result is already proved.

Comment: I disagree, the pair $(3,1)$ for example is an element of $A$ as well.

Comment: As well as $(2,1)$.

Comment: @Octavius you're right, I was thinking in terms of equality. I'll add the extra solutions! The argument is unchanged however.

Comment: Is it a bad way to prove if I list all of elements? I kind of want to prove it generally instead of specifying elements. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @so0jong no it's not a bad way at all. The general argument you could make could be that for two natural number $x$ and $y$, and a natural number $n$, then for $xy\leq n$ there is always only a finite number of solutions.

Comment: It's not a bad way to list them all, but you don't have to. You just have to prove there are finitely many of them. E.g. You could argue that since $xy \leq 4$ then $x \leq 4$ and $y \leq 4$ (supposing that $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$). But there are finitely many ways to satisfy each of the last two inequalities using natural numbers, thus there are finitely many ways to satisfy their conjunction